# Github action for desktop application don't work with error DesktopBridge not found

Tags: windows, yaml, github-actions

I'm using a github action to build, test and deploy my windows form application.

My yaml file contain this line of code

```
name: .NET Core Desktop

on:
    push:
    branches: [ master ]
    pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
    build:

    strategy:
        matrix:
            configuration: [Debug, Release]

    runs-on: windows-latest  

    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    
    with:
      fetch-depth: 0

    # Install the .NET Core workload
    - name: Install .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
          dotnet-version: 5.0.x

    # Add  MSBuild to the PATH: https://github.com/microsoft/setup-msbuild
    - name: Setup MSBuild.exe
      uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1.0.2

    name: Execute unit tests
    run: dotnet test
```

the packaging project contains line such as

> ```
> <PropertyGroup>
>     <WapProjPath Condition="'$(WapProjPath)'==''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\DesktopBridge\
>     </WapProjPath>    
> </PropertyGroup>    
> <Import Project="$(WapProjPath)\Microsoft.DesktopBridge.props" />
> ```

and the error is

C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\dotnet\sdk\5.0.400\Microsoft\DesktopBridge\Microsoft.DesktopBridge.props" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration

If I remove the packaging project it's work

What is DesktopBridge?

Is a file that I have to insert?

I've followed this instructions
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net

Comment: Getting same issue here, not sure what I should do to fix it.